# Create numpy array from dataFrame by Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame like:

[image]

There are one row per day and machine, and i need to create several numpy arrays just with the data in every column per PCSN.

I have created this function, but i takes like 5 minutes to get the results. And i think in pandas has be other solution to create this arrays faster.  I tried with groupby but i cant get the correct result.

```
def create_array(df,metrics):
    
    salida = []
    serial = [] # Save the serial number know which it is
    
    pbar = tqdm(total=len(df.PCSN.unique()))
    
    for numero in df.PCSN.unique():
        pbar.update(1)
        
        if len(df[metrics][df['PCSN']==numero].values)>256:
            inter = df[metrics][df['PCSN']==numero].values[-256:]   # get last 256 to create a figure 16*16
            salida.append(inter)
            serial.append(numero)
    print('Done for'+ metrics)
    pbar.close()
    return salida,serial
```

Thanks for your time ;)

I find the dolution finally with groupby, The solution could be

```
test = df.groupby('PCSN')['PrimDoseCal_6xFFF'].apply(list)
```

Comment: you can make use of `to_numpy()` method for converting `series` and `dataframe` easily to `ndarray` in `pandas` after doing your calculations

Comment: Yes, but the problem that i think i have is i need to looking for every single PCSN and then convert to a series or to numpy... I really want to know if i can group by PCSN and then convert all in one

Comment: I have found the solution with groupby.                          test=df_6xFFF.groupby('PCSN') ['PrimDoseCal_6xFFF'].apply(list)
Now i dont need to looking for every PCSN.